# How to calculate Specular value for Principled BSDF node from IOR?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, mathematics

With regard to the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/principled.html) the Specular value for the new Principled BSDF node can be computed with following formula:

$\text{specular}=\left(\frac{\text{ior}-1}{\text{ior}+1}\right)^2/0.08$
For example:

```
water: ior = 1.33, specular = 0.25
glass: ior = 1.5, specular = 0.5
diamond: ior = 2.417, specular = 2.15
```

But I am getting other numbers. Is the formula wrong? If so, what is the correct one?

Comment: The formula works for me, I get the same results. Are you maybe doing a sqrtf() instead of sqr()?

Comment: Yes... I was using square root by mistake. Thanks for pointing that out. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

The formula above is correct. Just don't mistake square with square root as I did before.